# Why can't multiprocess.Process call getattr method?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, getattr

Trying to call two methods `say_hello` and `say_world` by `getattr()` in `multiprocessing.Process`, but method `say_world` hasn't been executed. How can I make it possible? Thanks.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

class Hello:
    def say_hello(self):
        print('Hello')

    def say_world(self):
        print('World')


class MultiprocessingTest:
    def say_process(self, say_type):
        h = Hello()
        while True:
            if hasattr(h, say_type):
                    result = getattr(h, say_type)()
                    print(result)
            time.sleep(1)

    def report(self):
        Process(target=self.say_process('say_hello')).start()
        Process(target=self.say_process('say_world')).start() # This line hasn't been executed.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = MultiprocessingTest()
    t.report()
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `target` expects a reference to a function as value but your code passes `None` to it. These are the necessary parts to change:

```
class Hello:
    def say_hello(self):
        while True:
            print('Hello')
            time.sleep(1)

    def say_world(self):
        while True:
            print('World')
            time.sleep(1)

class MultiprocessingTest:
    def say_process(self, say_type):
        h = Hello()
        if hasattr(h, say_type):
            return getattr(h, say_type) # Return function reference instead of execute function
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: This solution works! Thanks. But I have tens of `say_xxx` method in which frequency of `time.sleep` aren't the same.

Comment: You can pass parameters to the target functions with `args`: `Process(target=self.say_process('say_hello'), args = (2, )).start()` where yo u have to declare your `say_xxx` methods as `def say_xxx(self, sleep_time)`.

Comment: You're right. I will add sleep in method `say_process` and method `say_xxx` can focus on its own business.